# using TreeSet to sort without providing a Comparator to it

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I know that `TreeSet` in java automatically sort its elements in ascending order an it guarantees the order.

for example, If i have an array of `Date` object in random and I copy it to `TreeSet` then it will be added in `TreeSet` in sorted way.

but suppose instead of a simple `Date` object, I have an `ArrayList` of `HashMap<String,Object>`, in the following format.

first value in arraylist,

```
{mydate = 32156464 , mystring = "abc", mystring2 = "xyz"}
```

2nd value in arraylist of hashmap,

```
{mydate = 64687678 , mystring = "abdc", mystring2 = "xyzzz"}
```

3rd value in arraylist of hashmap,

```
{mydate = 11233678 , mystring = "abxdc", mystring2 = "xyzppzz"}
```

Now if i want to sort this arraylist of hashmap based on `mydate` key, i have to create a new comparator in `TreeSet` instance like this,

```
public static Set<HashMap<String, Object>> mySet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> o1, HashMap<String, Object> o2) {
            return ((Date) o2.get(mydate)).compareTo((mydate) o1.get(DATE));
        }
    });
```

and it will store the arraylist inside the `TreeSet` in sorted order just fine. But I have used a custom `Comparator` to achieve this. What is the point of using `TreeSet` in this situation for sorting data if i am also providing a custom `Comparator` to it ?

How can i sort this `ArrayList` of `HashMap` based on `date` value without using a new instance of `Comparator` in `TreeSet` ?

Comment: The point of a sorted container is to keep your items in a particular order. A comparator is your means of specifying what determines that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the point of using TreeSet in this situation for sorting data if i am also providing a custom Comparator to it ?

Because it's the `TreeSet` code that keeps it sorted. You haven't had to provide any of the code for that - *all* you've had to provide is the custom comparison.

> How can i sort this ArrayList of HashMap based on date value without using a new instance of Comparator in TreeSet ?

You can't, directly. You could write a subclass of `HashMap` which implemented `Comparable` for itself, but that would seem a bit odd to me. For example:

```
public class SpecialMap extends HashMap<String, Object>
    implements Comparable<SpecialMap> {

    private final String key;

    public SpecialMap(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int compareTo(SpecialMap other) {
        // TODO: Null handling
        Date thisDate = (Date) this.get(key);
        Date otherDate = (Date) other.get(key);
        return thisDate.compareTo(otherDate);
    }
}
```

Then you could have an `ArrayList<SpecialMap>` and sort that.

But given that you've had to provide basically the same code as for the comparator *and* bound your comparison with the map type, it feels to me like it would be better just to stick with the comparator.

Comment: You could also wrap the `HashMap<String, Object>` in a class that implements `Comparable`, but I agree that it's quite odd. Providing a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't supply a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet`, then it will rely on its elements being `Comparable` to sort them.  If they're not `Comparable`, then a `ClassCastException` will result.  The [`TreeSet` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) explain:

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or by a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

But the `HashMap` class is not `Comparable`, so you must supply a custom `Comparator` so the `TreeSet` knows how you want to sort them.  You cannot sort your `HashMap`s without a `Comparator`, whether they're in a `TreeSet` or any other collection.

There are advantages to using a `TreeSet` in this situation.  The add, find, and remove operations are O(log n).  If you were to use an `ArrayList` for this, then add and remove operations would be O(n), even if the find operation would still be O(log n).

More from `TreeSet` javadocs:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using HashMap you could create a class that contains mydate, mystring, mystring2 and implements a Comparable interface.

However it's a good practice to use comparator because you'll be able to supply sorting criteria in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a comparator in a TreeSet is that you don't have write the code to do the actual sorting, you just provide a method that determines which of your objects is first, based on your comparison rules.
If you don't want to create a comparator, you would need to add to your collection objects that implement the Comparable interface.
To sort an ArrayList, use Collections.sort().